# Copy files from a list to a folder

Tags: linux, file, shell

i have a text file abc.txt and it's contents are,

```
    /lag/cnn/org/one.txt
   /lag/cnn/org/two.txt
   /lag/cnn/org/three.txt
```

if i use ,

```
tar -cvf allfiles.tar -T abc.txt
```

i am getting the tar of files in the list. Similarly is it possible to copy those files in abc.txt to a folder.

I tried ,

```
  cp --files-from test1.txt ./Folder
```

but it is not working. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `xargs`:

```
cat test1.txt | xargs -I{} cp {} ./Folder
```

In order to avoid [Useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html), you could say:

```
xargs -a test1.txt -I{} cp {} ./Folder
```

Comment: xargs worked and if i want to copy only a certain nymber of files from test1.txt how can i do that?

Comment: @user2572985 For copying a certain number of files, use the first form.  For example, saying: `head -10 test1.txt | xargs -I{} cp {} ./Folder` would the first 10 files listed in `test1.txt` to `./Folder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` for example, or do it in a loop:

```
while read FILE; do cp "$FILE" ./Folder; done <test1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
while IFS= read -r FILENAME ; do
    cp -- "$FILENAME" ./Folder || break
done < test1.txt
```

which loops over the lines of the file, reading each line into the variable `FILENAME`, and running `cp` for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tar cvf -` to write the tar to stdout and pipe it right into a `tar xvfC - Folder`.